# Error: package hyperloop does not exist

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, appc-hyperloop

I have created a new project and activated hyperloop. The information in tiapp.xml is correct (as in the documentation). When I create the Android app I get this error:

```
Package hyperloop does not exist
```

When creating the iOS app I get this error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.app/Test normal x86_64
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

It seems as if the module 'Hyperloop' could not be found? I can not find the error. I am using the titanium SDK 6.1.1GA.

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.5
  Architecture                = 64bit

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.8.4
  npm Version                 = 2.15.11

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.9
  Core Package                = 6.2.2

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.41

Alloy
  Alloy Version                = 1.9.13
```

**Hyperloop Requirements**

```
Titanium: 5.4.0+
SDK: 5.4.0+
CLI: 5.4.0+
Alloy: 1.8.0+
```

Which CLI must be changed to 5.4.0+? And how do I do that?

```
appc cli -v   => 6.2.2
appc ti -v    => 5.0.14 UPDATE??? HOW???
appc alloy -v => 1.9.11
```

The shortened tiapp.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>
    <ios>
        <use-jscore-framework>true</use-jscore-framework>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <modules>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="android">hyperloop</module>
        <module platform="iphone">hyperloop</module>
    </modules>
    <sdk-version>6.1.1.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>ti.alloy</plugin>
        <plugin>hyperloop</plugin>
    </plugins>
</ti:app>
```

Comment: what does your tiapp.xml look like?

Comment: @RenePot: See above. Thanks.

Comment: @RenePot: There are the same errors when I use a sample project.